# Add event reminders(customers can save dates and event names in their personal calendar-login required)

Tags: php, wordpress, notifications

I'm building an eCommerce website and couldn't find a way to:

“Add event reminders(customers can save dates and event names in their personal calendar-login required). The system will send an email reminder and reminder at login on upcoming events.”

So far I have fetched user’s event info using contact form 7 and contact form 7 date picker. Now I need help regarding “System will send an email reminder and reminder at login on upcoming events.”

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Please add more details, on what did you try so far, and what didn't work

Comment: I used CF7 to fetch user information. Also I used Flamingo plugin to store CF7 information in WP database. Regarding the task, do I have to create a plugin that will read the data from CF7 and check if the user has logged in before showing the reminders or it can be done by running a script on database?